# How to get id of drawable?

Tags: android, bitmap, resize, drawable, identifier

I search a way to resize image efficiently avoiding "OutOfMemory".
To do this, I've tried this method : http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html
To use these methods I must have a drawable identifier, so I create a drawable like that :

```
Drawable image = Drawable.createFromPath(pathName);
```

And now I don't know how to get the drawable identifier.
The method `getIdentifier()` implies to have the drawable name, but I hav'nt.

Comment: why do ypu need an ID?

Comment: I need the ID to use the mehod : BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, drawableID, options);

Comment: @Maxime: Can't you directly get the id by R.drawable.yourImageName ?

Comment: you probably need decodeFile(String, BitmapFactory.Options)

Comment: The drawable is generated from a file downloaded by user, so the file is not in drawables folder.

If I use decodeFile() I get a OutOfMemory, and I don't want to loop decreasing SampleSize. This solution is too bad for performances.

Comment: if you dont want to use SampleSize so why do you want to use decodeResource with Options?

Answer (score 0):

> To use these methods I must have a drawable identifier, so I create a drawable like that :
>
> Drawable image = Drawable.createFromPath(pathName);

First thing, you don't need to create a drawable. Secondly, if you don't have an image in your drawable folder then u should not use

```
BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resId, options)
```

BitmapFactory also have other methods such as

```
BitmapFactory.decodeFile (String filePath, options); //it takes your image filepath 
(in case your image is in Sdcard) as a string.
or,
BitmapFactory.decodeStream (InputStream, options); // if the image is placed in your asset folder instead of drawables.
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answers.
I've finally choos this method to resize pictures :

```
private void resizeBitmap(String path) {
        Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        int sampleSize = 0;
        boolean done = false;
        Bitmap source = null;
        while (!done) {
            options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
            sampleSize++;
            try {
                options.inSampleSize = sampleSize;
                source = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, options);
                done = true;
            } catch (OutOfMemoryError e) {

            }
            if (sampleSize > 20) {
                // Exit to avoid infinite loop
                done = true;
            }
        }
        if (source != null) {
            try {
                FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(path);
                source.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, out);
                out.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("RESIZE PICTURE", "Unable to resize picture after download : "+e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }
```